# Sound Effect made on vocal and guitar

Tags: sound-effects

:)
I've come across an effect used in metalcore

It's right at the beginning just before the screaming starts.
I think the sound is the scream itself or at least a scream edited in some way..
How do I create it?
Another similar effect was done on a guitar and I'm wondering how to create this one as well:)

(1:42)
It'd be great if anyone could help me with that!!!:D

Answer (score 1):

The vocal effect sounds to me like a long reverb tail that has been reversed.

The guitar effect may not necessarily even be a reverb tail, maybe just the guitar sampled with a rising envelope on the volume.